# TSQL: Find part of string based on a column in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to extract the school name from a file name string.  I put all of the schools in a temp table and I need to use the temp table column of SchoolName to search the string.  This filename is inherited and should be a one time event to try to extract data from.

The SchoolCode and SchoolName are in the temp table.  If the SchoolName matches what's in the temp table, I would like the SchoolCode as well.

I tried doing a subquery in the WHERE clause but I get an error stating it returned more than one result.

**Current data:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

**Test Code:**

```
 DROP TABLE #SchoolName
 GO

 CREATE TABLE #SchoolName (
  FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX)
 )

 INSERT INTO #SchoolName
 ( FILENAME  )
 VALUES
  ('New Student added 10-02-16\High School\2015\North Side HS\JONES, JIMMY E_07-29-1993_2314687.PDF')
 ,('2006\South Side HIGH SCHOOL\GRADUATE\Johnson Jack B,03-19-1989,7123444.PDF')
 ,('2010\Riverwood\GRADUATES\Harmon, Kardon C_07-21-1991_370143.PDF')
 ,('2009\RockCreek\GRADUATES\Vandolay, Art E_09-23-1974_7210122.PDF')

 DROP TABLE #SchoolsList

 CREATE TABLE #SchoolsList (
  SchoolCode VARCHAR(4)
 ,School varchar(500)
 )
 INSERT INTO #SchoolsList
 (
        SchoolCode
    ,  School
 )

 VALUES

 (1111  ,'North Side '),(1112   ,'South Side '),(1113   ,'Riverwood  '),(1114   ,'RockCreek')
```

Comment: You forgot to post the query that results in the error.   We need to see that to help debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
SELECT SL.*
FROM SchoolsList SL JOIN SchoolName SN
ON SN.FileName LIKE CONCAT('%\', RTRIM(LTRIM(SL.School)), '%');
-- You can remove LTRIM() if there is no spaces in the begining
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bbf3eae3db35120b60ec6646879642cb)**

Answer (score 2):

You can join to your SchoolList table using a like (assuming your school list is actually a distinct list)

```
 SELECT l.SchoolCode, n.*
 FROM #SchoolName n
 LEFT OUTER JOIN #SchoolsList l
    ON n.FILENAME LIKE '%' + l.School + '%'
```

Riverwood doesn't return a code since you have a space in the school list (SS and NS work since there is actually a space after them in both the filename and the school list)

Comment: Thank you @TTeeple!  This works.  The accepted answer handles the spaces a little more the way I want.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! I personally don't like modifying what is supposed to be a master list.  I think the correct thing is to remove the leading/trailing spaces from the list, then let the query do it's natural thing.  Glad you got it working though!